# Vertical Icon Bar in Foundation not taking up full height

Tags: html, css, ember.js, handlebars.js, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation to style my Ember app.  I am trying to create a side icon bar for navigation on the left side.  However, the bar will not take up the full height of the screen as I would like it too.  Any ideas on why this is happening?

Here is my handlebars template:

```
<div class="icon-bar vertical five-up">
  <a class="item">
    <i class="fi-home"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    <i class="fi-bookmark"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    <i class="fi-info"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    <i class="fi-mail"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    <i class="fi-like"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in CSS, it'll make the application ember element the height of the viewport:

```
body > .ember-view{
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

If you right click your webpage -> inspect element and familiarize yourself with the element inspector, you could pretty easily figure out this issue btw.